# What is this blue thing in a photograph of a bright light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics, camera

It looks like the bulb of the lamp beside it but how why what

[image]

Comment: That's funky indeed. Please provide the full make & model of the camera you used to take this - the details of the answer depend on the internals of the camera and those change from device to device.

Comment: Related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69043

Comment: An escapee from [JJ Abrams](http://www.theverge.com/2013/9/30/4788758/j-j-abrams-apologizes-for-his-overusing-lens-flares)’ workshop.

Comment: I take it there is no frosted shade / diffuser around the lightbulb and that if the bulb is enclosed in anything, the enclosure is clear and not frosted. If so, then Martin's answer is good. If not, then we need another explanation!

Answer (score 42):

It is the bright light from the bub reflecting off the image sensor in the  camera, then reflecting off the back of one of the lenses and then hitting a different bit of the sensor where it is detected.

Even if the sensor is absorbing 95% of the light hitting it (ideally you want the sensor to absorb 100%) and the lenses reflect only 5% you still have 5% * 5% = 0.25% of the light from the bulb hitting the sensor for the second time - so the blue image is 400x fainter than the white bulb. That's why you only see the effect for bright sources like the light bulb or the sun.

The reason it is blue is likely that both the sensor and the lens have coatings to reduce the amount of reflection. These don't reduce all colors by the same amount, the sensor is also more sensitive at some colors and so might detect fainter blue than red.

Comment: The blueish color also makes me think effects from an anti-reflective coating. and reminds me of color shifted mirror images that can occur on glasses.  Mine right now under a single LED lamp bulb: http://imgur.com/TegaCQm

Comment: Is your explanation still consistent with the observed vertical inversion (/180° rotation?) of the image?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty you would expect it to be directly opposite the source relative to the center of the optical axis. At least if the lens axis and sensor are well aligned.

Comment: I don't mean the *position* of the image, I mean the *orientation* of the image, which appears to be inverted. That wouldn't happen with the double reflection you describe.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty See the last section [here](http://toothwalker.org/optics/flare.html), and also [here](http://toothwalker.org/optics/filterflare.html) for more examples. These Ghost images are indeed mirror images of the original bright object.

Comment: @Mostafa Huh. I'm still not clear on why that works, but it's probably worth [its own separate question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303622/why-are-filter-flare-images-centrally-inverted).

Answer (score 22):

It's a **[lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare)** of the spiral bulb in the socket.

I assume this is the full uncropped picture. Then the bulb and lens flare position are symmetric with respect to the center of the image (in other words, the *optical axis*).

Similar lens flares are typically seen in images of the sun, for example in Apollo footage; moon hoax conspiracy theorists get all worked up about them :-)

Here's a picture of such a bulb. If you examine the above picture carefully, you can see the spiral and the diagonal segment.

[image: Spiral light bulb]

Comment: Same thing happened when my friend took a picture of a "blue moon". He never shuts up about it, and since he wrote off SE as being, "a bunch of idiots on the internet," I'll never hear the end of it.

Comment: Isn't this more appropriately described as a [filter flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare#Filter_flare)?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty No: lens flare is the standard term, and lenses without filters flare too -- filters just add more air-glass surfaces which doesn't help any.

Comment: @tfb That seems not to be the case from the materials I have found. Can you provide references that use the term 'lens flare' specifically for this phenomenon?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I have images with ghosts in which were made with lenses without filters on them (planar or near-planar elements are more than sufficient).  I can't unfortunately show them as they're negs which I've not printed.

Comment: @tfb That's not the point: yes, they can be produced by other optical elements, but the point here is just the name. You claim it's a standard term, in which case there should be plenty of resources that use it that way.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty trust me, lens flare is a very standard term.  But clearly you know best.

Comment: @tfb I'm happy to be corrected; I can only speak to the usage in the resources I have seen (listed in the linked question), and the conspicuous lack of 'ghost' images in google image searches for lens flare. However, if it *is* standard to use 'lens flare' for images like [this](http://toothwalker.org/optics/flare/ufo.jpg) (in *addition* to the more typical usage of the term, for images like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/High-quality_lens_flare_rendering.png)), then surely there are plenty of resources to showcase and this does not need to be left to trust.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: The image posted by the OP is similar to your second linked image. The difference is the lenses. The OP used a single element lens so his lens flare will have just one ghost image. The image in your link used a more complex lens (probably from a professional camera) and thus have multiple ghosts of the bright object. The first image you link looks very different but may still be a lens flare. However it most probably is a mirage.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I simply went to Wikipedia to validate the term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare I frankly don't understand the fundamental difference you're concerned about with the two images you linked. Both show the same effect, so why would they have different words used to describe them?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I even linked the term to Wikipedia in my answer. That should convince anybody the term exists.

Comment: @ToddWilcox You mean the Filter Flare section of the Wikipedia page? They are both well described as flares, but that does not mean they're the same thing. If you can't see the difference between the two images I just linked to them I frankly can't help you.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty A filter flare uses *exactly* the same mechanics as a lens flare.  The only difference is which surfaces get reflected off of.  The only reason to distinguish them is that a photographer who is using a filter should be aware that some reflections that they see may be reflected off of a filter, and thus could be resolved by removing the filter, while some reflections are purely within the lens.  Fundamentally, both are just secondary light paths reflecting off the optics.